# How to export a large list of variables in Bash?

Tags: environment-variables, variable, syntax

I use Bash 4.3.48(1) and I have a `.sh` file containing about 20 variables right under the shebang. The file contains only variables.

This is the pattern:

```
x="1"
y="2"
...
```

I need to export all these variables in a [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) way: For example, one `export` to all vars, instead say 20 `export` for 20 vars.

What's the most elegant way (shortest, most efficient by all means) to do that **inside** that file?

A `for` loop? An `array`? maybe something simpler than these (some kind of collection sugar syntax)?

Comment: Or just put them all in one export line?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `set -a` (or the equivalent `set -o allexport`) at the top of your file to enable the `allexport` shell option. Then use `set +a` (or `set +o allexport`) at the end of the file (wherever appropriate) to disable the `allexport` shell option.

Using enabling the `allexport` shell option will have the following effect (from the `bash` manual):

> Each variable or function that is created or modified is
>                         given the export attribute and marked for export to the
>                         environment of subsequent commands.

This shell option, set with either `set -a` or`set -o allexport`, is [defined in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set) (and should therefore be available in all `sh`-like shells) as

> When this option is on, the *export* attribute shall be set for each variable to which an assignment is performed; [...] If the assignment precedes a utility name in a command, the *export* attribute shall not persist in the current execution environment after the utility completes, with the exception that preceding one of the special built-in utilities causes the *export* attribute to persist after the built-in has completed. If the assignment does not precede a utility name in the command, or if the assignment is a result of the operation of the `getopts` or `read` utilities, the *export* attribute shall persist until the variable is unset.

The variables set while this option is enabled will be exported, i.e. made into environment variables. These environment variables will be available to the current shell environment and to any subsequently created child process environments, as per usual.

This means that you will have to either

- source this file (using `.`, or `source` in shells that have this command), or
- start the processes that should have access to the variables from this file.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a hack:

```
source <(sed 's/^/export /' file.sh)
```

I assume your shell is like bash and supports [process substitutions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution)

Or, edit the file itself:

```
sed -i 's/[^=]\+/export &; &/' file.sh
```

Comment: I guess you can also use `$0` when doing it from the same file (in the end of the file, under all variable declarations).

Comment: @user9303970 If you mean putting the `sed` command that changes `file.sh` into `file.sh` itself, I don't think that'll work. Modifying a script file while a process is running that file itself tends to cause problems. Anyway, if you put the `sed` command at the end, by the time the shell gets to it, it will already have done the variable assignments, so it'll be too late.

Comment: If you're going to edit "file.sh" just put the export commands in.

Comment: OP asked about doing it from **inside** the file, so the `source` + `sed` solution is no good. The other solution also doesn’t work because they specifically asked to not have all those explicit `export`s in the file.

Comment: If there are spaces inside the environment variables, you'll need to add quotes around them, making this: `source <(sed 's/^/export "/' file.sh | sed 's/$/"/')`